# function becomes undefined when passed to another function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a typewriter function but `func` in function `typewrite` becomes `undefined`.

```js
var txtElems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-txt]");
txtElems = Array.from(txtElems);
typewriteAll(txtElems, 70);
function typewriteAll(elemArr, delay) {
 if (elemArr.length) {
  typewrite(
   elemArr[0],
   elemArr[0].dataset.txt,
   delay,
   typewriteAll, elemArr.slice(1), delay
  );
 }
}

function typewrite(Elem, t, delay, func, arg1, arg2) {
 let txt = String(t);
 (txt != "")
  ? (() => {
   Elem.innerHTML += txt[0];
   setTimeout(
    () => {
     typewrite(
      Elem,
      txt.slice(1, txt.length),
      delay
     )
    }, delay)
   })()
  : (() => {
   setTimeout(
    () => {
     Elem.setAttribute("typing", "end");
     func(arg1, arg2)
    }, 10 * delay
   );
  })()
}
```

```html
<div data-txt="Some text to type"></div>
<div data-txt="Some more text to type..."></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried making `typewrite` a fat arrow function?

Comment: Because there’s a call to `typewrite` in there where you’re *not* passing a forth argument…!?

Comment: a smaller snip will help members debug the issue in a better manner.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer That wouldn't help, the OP doesn't use `this` inside the function, which could cause similar issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function calls work fine, the problem is, that inside the `typewrite`'s `setTimeout` callback, (when you recall `typewrite`), you forgotten to pass the callback and its parameters to itself, so they are defined only during the first iteration.

To make it work, pass all arguments to itself:

```js
var txtElems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-txt]");
txtElems = Array.from(txtElems);
typewriteAll(txtElems, 70);
function typewriteAll(elemArr, delay) {
    if (elemArr.length) {
        typewrite(
            elemArr[0],
            elemArr[0].dataset.txt,
            delay,
            typewriteAll, elemArr.slice(1), delay
        );
    }
}

function typewrite(Elem, t, delay, func, arg1, arg2) {
    let txt = String(t);
    if(txt != ""){
        Elem.innerHTML += txt[0];
        setTimeout(() => {
            typewrite(
                Elem,
                txt.slice(1, txt.length),
                delay,
                //here:
                func,
                arg1,
                arg2
            )
        }, delay)
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
                Elem.setAttribute("typing", "end");
                func(arg1, arg2)
        }, 10 * delay)
    }
}
```

```html
<div data-txt="Some text to type"></div>
<div data-txt="Some more text to type..."></div>
```

And if you're creating typewriter effects, I **highly** recommend you to use `setInterval` and ES6 generator functions, as they make the code **much** readable... and helps you avoid making such mistakes:

```js
function typewrite(element, text, delay){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const iterator = (function*() {
      try{
        for(const letter of text){
          element.textContent += letter
          yield
        }
        element.setAttribute("typing", "end");
        resolve()
      }catch(e){
        reject(e)
      }finally{
        clearTimeout(interval)
      }
    })()
    const interval = setInterval(() => iterator.next(), delay);
    iterator.next()
  })
}

function typewriteAll(elems, delay){
  return elems.reduce((acc,elem) => acc.then(() => typewrite(elem, elem.dataset.txt, delay)), Promise.resolve())
}

var txtElems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-txt]");
txtElems = Array.from(txtElems);
typewriteAll(txtElems, 70)
```

```html
<div data-txt="Some text to type"></div>
<div data-txt="Some more text to type..."></div>
```